# How can I detect when a stream client is no longer available in PHP (eg network cable pulled out)

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, stream

Is there any way (other than checking for ping responses) to detect when a client stream (I don't know if a stream would be any different from sockets) becomes unavailable (ie there is no longer any connection but no clean disconnection was made)?

Using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$socket = stream_socket_server(
    'tcp://192.168.1.1:47700',
    $errno,
    $errstr,
    STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,
    stream_context_create(
        array(),
        array()
    )
);
if (!$socket) {
    echo 'Could not listen on socket'."\n";
}
else {
    $clients = array((int)$socket => $socket);
    $last = time();
    while(true) {
        $read = $clients;
        $write = null;
        $ex = null;
        stream_select(
            $read,
            $write,
            $ex,
            5
        );
        foreach ($read as $sock) {
            if ($sock === $socket) {
                echo 'Incoming on master...'."\n";
                $client = stream_socket_accept(
                    $socket,
                    5
                );
                if ($client) {
                    stream_set_timeout($client, 1);
                    $clients[(int)$client] = $client;
                }
            }
            else {
                echo 'Incoming on client '.((int)$sock)."...\n";
                $length = 1400;
                $remaining = $length;

                $buffer = '';
                $metadata['unread_bytes'] = 0;
                do {
                    if (feof($sock)) {
                        break;
                    }

                    $result = fread($sock, $length);

                    if ($result === false) {
                        break;
                    }

                    $buffer .= $result;

                    if (feof($sock)) {
                        break;
                    }

                    $continue = false;

                    if (strlen($result) == $length) {
                        $continue = true;
                    }

                    $metadata = stream_get_meta_data($sock);
                    if ($metadata && isset($metadata['unread_bytes']) && $metadata['unread_bytes']) {
                        $continue = true;
                        $length = $metadata['unread_bytes'];
                    }
                } while ($continue);

                if (strlen($buffer) === 0 || $buffer === false) {
                    echo 'Client disconnected...'."\n";
                    stream_socket_shutdown($sock, STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
                    unset($clients[(int)$sock]);
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Received: '.$buffer."\n";
                }
                echo 'There are '.(count($clients) - 1).' clients'."\n";
            }

        }
        if ($last < (time() - 5)) {
            foreach ($clients as $id => $client) {
                if ($client !== $socket) {
                    $text = 'Yippee!';
                    $ret = fwrite($client, $text);
                    if ($ret !== strlen($text)) {
                        echo 'There seemed to be an error sending to the client'."\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
if ($socket) {
    stream_socket_shutdown($socket, STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
}
```

and a sockets client on a different computer, I can connect to the server, send and receive data, and disconnect cleanly and everything functions as expected. If, however, I pull the network connection on the client computer, nothing is detected on the server side - the server keeps on listening to the client socket, and also writes to it without any error manifesting itself.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, calling `feof($stream)` will tell you if the remote socket disconnected, but I'm not absolutely certain about that. I'm using ping/pong myself while continuing to research a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a socket timeout, in which case you get an error if a client does not respond in a timely fashion.

Check PHP's stream_set_timeout function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php

Also check socket_set_option:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-option.php

and finally, check out this great article on how to use sockets in PHP effectively:
"PHP Socket Programming, done the Right Way™"
http://christophh.net/2012/07/24/php-socket-programming/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but, if you look at the code, you can see that I already use `stream_set_timeout` to set a timeout of 1 sec and (code that I didn't include above) when I echo the stream metadata (`echo 'Client #'.$id.' gives: '.serialize(stream_get_meta_data($client))."\n";`) every 5 secs, the `timedout` is always `false`.

Comment: Have you checked socket_set_option()? You can set the socket to use keep-alives with the SO_KEEPALIVE option

Comment: For a stream rather than a socket, I presume it is more likely to be `stream_context_set_option` however, as far as I am aware, the TCP KEEPALIVE intervals are OS dependant (not on a per-PHP-socket basis), and the default interval is quite a high value, whereas I am looking to consider a client as timed out after a few seconds.

Comment: For the moment I have just implemented a `PING - PONG` system, but I was just wondering whether there was something better equipped to do this for me at the PHP level.